# CSS3; keep caption width the same as the image

Tags: width, caption, figure

I'd like to have the caption text stay the same width as the image (without setting one fixed width).  I've tried playing around with , etc., but that's even harder to control.

Here's a sample of the CSS.  Hope this is the proper way to ask questions here!

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        #floatrightphoto {
        float:right;
        padding: 6px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-left-width: 1px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-top-color: #CCEE77;
        border-right-color: #AFE165;
        border-bottom-color: #AFE165;
        border-left-color: #CCEE77;
        background-color: #CCFF99;
        }

        #floatrightphoto  p{
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #889260;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: -3px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 1px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        text-align: right;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", Ariel;
        font-style: oblique;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 16px;
        position: static;
        display: inherit;
        }
        body {
        width: 750px;
        }
        -->
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="floatrightphoto">
    <img src="somephoto" width="180" height="180">
      <br>
        <p>Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption
        Caption Caption</p>
      </br>
    </img>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoa that's a whole lotta extra fluff. I'm looking for the same solution.

I came across this solution (modified to reflect what you are wanting):

```
#img-right{display: table; min-width: 1px; float:right; margin-left: 10px;}
#img-right p {display: table-caption; caption-side: bottom;}
```

However, this works in most all browsers except IE where in IE my `#img-right` spans the full width of the caption (the caption being longer than the image itself and it doesn't wrap). I am still trying to figure out how to make IE behave, as it works perfectly in other browsers.

As for your other code, I suggest simplifying it a bit to reduce load time. I modified your CSS a little bit...I'd suggest renaming the ID's to be smaller and easier to read, please, **don't EVER use Comic Sans... *ever.*** :)

```
body { width: 750px; }
#img-right {
        float:right;
        padding: 6px;
        margin: 3px 2px 2px 0px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccee77;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccee77;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #afe165;
        border-right: 1px solid #afe165; 
        background: #ccff99;
        }

#img-right p{
        font: italic 14px/16px Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Sans, Verdana;  
        color: #889260;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px 0px -3px 1px;
        text-align: right;
        }
```